# Issue need to press the back to input in android

Tags: android

I have registration screen in android. When user start to type then to enter the value in next EditText then need to press the back then type and so on.

Please help me such user need not to press back button many times to input.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/senderphoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="SENDER PHONE NUMBER" 
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="RECIEVER PHONE NUMBER" 
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@id/senderphoneNumber"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="TEXT MESSAGE" 
        android:layout_below="@id/phoneNumber"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/mmsCentralURL"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="MMS CENTRAL URL" 
        android:layout_below="@id/messageText"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/proxyURL"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="MMS PROXY" 
        android:layout_below="@id/mmsCentralURL" 
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

     <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/port"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="MMS PORT" 
        android:layout_below="@id/proxyURL" 
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chooseImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:text="PICK IMAGE" 
        android:layout_below="@id/port"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:text="SEND" 
        android:layout_below="@id/chooseImage"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/emptyTV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/sendButton"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use android:imeOptions="actionDone" on last edittext

**For Next** - `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`

**For Done** - `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

-**Or**-

You can also go with `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/next_edit_text"`

Check this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

Comment: Should I use `For Next - android:imeOptions="actionNext"` this also. Or its enough to write the android:imeOptions="actionDone" on last edittext

Comment: Its not working `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/next_edit_text"` I added on the name but still i need to press back button to enter to next field.

Comment: You can use `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` for all the editTexts except the last one. For the last EditText use `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Comment: While typing you should get a Next button on keyboard from third EditText, according to code you posted. Does the keyboard show Next button when you are typing in the third EditText ?